# Python Asyncio / Websockets - why I don't see the output in my IDE (Spyder)

Tags: python-asyncio

I try to authenticate a user via websocket (link to documentation: https://docs.deribit.com/?python#public-auth). However, I do not see the expected output in my IDE (Spyder). 
Does something need to be changed in the code (I provide below  as well the expected output based on the API documentation).

Input:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

client_id = 'xxx'
client_secret = 'xxx'

msg = \
{
  "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
  "id" : 9929,
  "method" : "public/auth",
  "params" : {
    "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
    "client_id" : client_id,
    "client_secret" : client_secret
  }
}

async def call_api(msg):
   async with websockets.connect('wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
       await websocket.send(msg)
       while websocket.open:
           response = await websocket.recv()
           # do something with the response...
           print(response)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 9929,
  "result": {
      "access_token": "1582628593469.1MbQ-J_4.CBP-OqOwm_FBdMYj4cRK2dMXyHPfBtXGpzLxhWg31nHu3H_Q60FpE5_vqUBEQGSiMrIGzw3nC37NMb9d1tpBNqBOM_Ql9pXOmgtV9Yj3Pq1c6BqC6dU6eTxHMFO67x8GpJxqw_QcKP5IepwGBD-gfKSHfAv9AEnLJkNu3JkMJBdLToY1lrBnuedF3dU_uARm",
      "expires_in": 31536000,
      "refresh_token": "1582628593469.1GP4rQd0.A9Wa78o5kFRIUP49mScaD1CqHgiK50HOl2VA6kCtWa8BQZU5Dr03BhcbXPNvEh3I_MVixKZXnyoBeKJwLl8LXnfo180ckAiPj3zOclcUu4zkXuF3NNP3sTPcDf1B3C1CwMKkJ1NOcf1yPmRbsrd7hbgQ-hLa40tfx6Oa-85ymm_3Z65LZcnCeLrqlj_A9jM",
      "scope": "connection mainaccount",
      "token_type": "bearer"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add more prints to test where your program gets stuck? Perhaps the remote server is slow or inoperational?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. As a total beginner in asyncio, how would I do that?

However, I think the feedback is fine as I get the right feedback when I use the websocket library (see below code). The problem here is that the process runs forever. I understand that asnycio is better suited here as it has .run_until_complete functionality.

```
import websocket, json


client_id = 'xxx'
client_secret = 'xxx'


def on_open(ws):
    print("opened connection")

    subscribe_msg = \
    {
      "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
      "id" : 9929,
      "method" : "public/auth",
      "params" : {
        "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
        "client_id" : client_id,
        "client_secret" : client_secret
      }
    }

    ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_msg))


def on_message(ws, message):
    print("received message")
    print(json.loads(message))


socket = 'wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2'

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message = on_message)

ws.run_forever()
```